# Exclude umbraco and umbraco_client from Publish

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco, publish

I am attempting to exclude umbraco, umbraco_client, and media folders from publishing via visual studio. I have followed the steps in the previous question: [excluding folders from Visual Studio 2015 publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574562/excluding-folders-from-visual-studio-2015-publication) and it doesn't work for me.

I copied the code in the linked question but still the umbraco folders were published. .wpp.targets File is in the same folder as the .csproj file with the same name as the csproj file

Copied the code in the previous link... saved the file. Closed visual studio and re-opened it. Even went one further and restarted my system.
Opened VS and tried to publish... both umbraco and umbraco_client were still published.
Notes: both folders are not included in the SLN/CSPROJ.